# SQL sorting question

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve all of the values in a table, sorted alphabetically and attach 'All' to the top (All is not in the table).

Current code:

```
SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type]
UNION
SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type ORDER BY 2
```

This orders everything, including All, which is problematic as I have a value in this table called 'Agreement' which after the sort shows up before All.

Is there any way I can return a list with 'All' at the top and everything else sorted below it?

UPDATE:

I tried the solution suggested by Andomar and Conrad, however I get the following error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'Type'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `case` to sort 'All' up front:

```
SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type]
UNION
SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type 
ORDER BY case when Type = 'All' then 1 else 2 end, Type
```

EDIT: Per your comment, SQL Server doesn't allow to `order by` on an alias.  Use a subquery:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type]
        UNION
        SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type 
        ) as SubQueryAlias
ORDER BY case when Type = 'All' then 1 else 2 end, Type
```

Or in this case, because the Type is an actual table field and not an alias, swap both parts of the union:

```
SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type 
UNION
SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type]
ORDER BY case when Type = 'All' then 1 else 2 end, Type
```

Comment: @JGow: Right, SQL Server annoyingly doesn't allow aliases without a subquery.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

Along with Andomar's answers you can also do this to get around the alias issue.

```
WITH CTE As 
(

    SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type]
    UNION
    SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type 
    ORDER BY 
)
SELECT
    typeID,
    Type,
FROM 
      CTE 
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
       WHEN  TypeID = 0 THEN typeID
       ELSE Type 
    END
```

but this assumes that all values of tbl_type.type are greater than 0

you can also just add an additional field to the cte

```
WITH CTE As 
(

    SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type], 1 as sortorder
    UNION
    SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type, 2 as sortorder
    ORDER BY 
)
SELECT
    typeID,
    Type,
FROM 
      CTE 
ORDER BY 
   sortorder,
   type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type] UNION SELECT TypeID, [Type] FROM tbl_Type ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a third column to sort on that indicates whether or not it's a data record (or the "All")

SELECT 0 AS TypeID, 'All' AS [Type], 0 AS IsDataRecord
UNION
SELECT TypeID, [Type], 1 AS IsDataRecord
FROM tbl_Type ORDER BY 3, 2